# How do i pass multiple params to the gorilla mux router endponit?

Tags: go, routes, gorilla

I am getting error like **" cannot refer to unexported name controllers.GetProducts"** when passing more than one param in the below routing endpoint. Am i doing anything wrong below?

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", controllers.HomeHandler).Methods("GET","OPTIONS")
    r.HandleFunc("/products/{expiry_date}/{brand}/{quality_rating}", controllers.GetProducts).Methods("GET","OPTIONS")

    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

In the controllers.go file, i have a declaration for GetProducts().

What i am doing wrong in the router syntax?

Comment: Nowhere in the shown code are you referencing `controllers.ProductsHandler`, so the error _"cannot refer to unexported name controllers.ProductsHandler"_ MUST be caused by some other code. Please share the code that causes the error.

Comment: John, are you sure it's `controllers.GetProducts` and not `controllers.getProducts`? Also, is the error from the go compiler (e.g., `go build`), or from an IDE (e.g. VSCode, GoLand, etc.)?

Comment: It is controllers.GetProducts only. I am getting the error while building the main.go. Can you please confirm the way i am passing multiple param in the route is correct?

Comment: The error looks like a compilation or linter error, so I don't think it has anything to do with the string passed to `r.HandleFunc`.

Comment: What version of Go are you using? Do you have any additional linters other than what's executed by `go build`? Can you show the `controllers.go` file and the code that declares the `GetProducts` handler (make sure to copy-paste the declaration verbatim)?